# Evaluating less obvious Taylor substitutions

Tags: calculus

I already understand the basics behind deriving taylor polynomial expressions from function derivatives. However, I'm struggling with using substitutions to create more complex taylor polynomials. For example (from my textbook),

$f(x) = {x(1-x^2)}^{3/2}$

How would one go about generating a McLaurin expression using only substitutions?

Answer (score 1):

Implicitly consider $-1<x<1$.

Using the binomial expansion:

$$(1-x)^{3/2}=1-\frac{3}{2}x+3\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{(2n-3)!!}{2^n\cdot n!}x^n$$

So we must just let $x\to x^2$: $$(1-x^2)^{3/2}=1-\frac{3}{2}x^2+3\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{(2n-3)!!}{2^n\cdot n!}x^{2n}$$And then multiply through by $x$: $$x(1-x^2)^{3/2}=x-\frac{3}{2}x^3+3\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{(2n-3)!!}{2^n\cdot n!}x^{2n+1}$$

This is valid by the uniqueness of Maclaurin coefficients.

Comment: This is really insightful! I'm curious as to how I would approach the same problem but building off of a pre existing function which I know the taylor series polynomial for - the one I have in mind is 1/(1-x) ?

Comment: @Rammie Why would you use $1/(1-x)$ to compute the series expansion for $x(1-x^2)^{3/2}$?